# How to use html tables within tumblr posts

Tags: html-table, tumblr

For a public blog we are currently using the default rich text editor.
This as content editors are no html writers.

Now on a certain post / custom page we want to add tabular data using a html table.
The rich text editor in tumblr has no support for creating tables so we switched to the html editor. There we created the table tag and some rows. Everything looks fine until saving the post. On saving the table element seems to be gone...

Comment: Did you check the HTML source code of the post? I can perfectly add tables to posts. (However, they don’t seem to be visible on the dashboard.)

Answer (score 1):

The Tumblr dashboard strips out many different HTML tags. They're visible in your theme, but on the dash they're either removed without a trace or replaced with a small clickthrough "embedded content" symbol.

If you NEED the table on the dash, you may need to use an image. Personally I'd include the Read More break to direct people into viewing the whole thing on your blog, but that won't work inside the app or slide-in bar, etc.